# .append() to the newly created element with the same class as others on the page

Tags: jquery

Ok, i am trying to dynamically add items to a page, but I am having an issue when I add more than one item, because the HTML gets appended multiple times to all the elements with the same class. I've tried playing around with .closest and .parents but can't seem to get it to work.

```
$('#addInquiryItem').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function () {

var x = $("#addInquiryItem").serializeArray();
  $(".added-inquiry").append (
    '<div class=row>' +
     '<div class="large-8 large-offset-2 column">'+
      '<div class="added-inquiry-item">' +
      '<a class="edit-inquiry-item">' +'<span class="fi-wrench iconic-sm" title="edit" aria-hidden="true">' + '</span>' + '</a>' +
     '</div>'
         );

$.each(x, function(i, field){
     $(".added-inquiry-item").append(
          '<input type="hidden" name="' + field.name + '" value="' + field.value + '"/>' +
          '<span class="' + field.name + '">' + field.value + '</span>'
      );
 });

 $(".added-inquiry").closest(".added-inquiry-item").append(
   '</div>' +
   '</div>'
  );

$(this).trigger("reset");
});
```

You can see that the problem is that when there are multiple .added-inquiry-item divs on the page, the content gets appended to every .added-inquiry-item div not only the one that is freshly created.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you please add the markup for `#addInquiryItem` and I don't quite understand what markup you are trying to achieve as a result. 
Your main mistakes are clear though. First, you need to be more specific with your selector - for example store a reference to created item in a variable. And use jQuery `find` method to select items only inside the created item. Second, I see you are appending closing tags at the end - which is not the best idea. Consider creating an html string with correct markup first and then appending in one go to the desired item.

Comment: @Olga Hey olga, #addInquiryItem is a form id, so I don't think the markup here is that important. Basically the parent element is always .added-inquiry in which multiple children get added with the class .added-inquiry-item.

Comment: Ok, I see, then I believe my comment contains steps to solving your problem. Please, tell me if you need more explanation.

Comment: @Olga how do i target just the created item with find? :) Thank you very much.